# jquery does div contain children of a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have an event handler that triggers an event handler that needs to test if the children of a div contain a certain class.

For now, I'm doing this:

```
$('#Container .DivData').live({
  mouseenter: function () {
    if ($(this).find('.HiddenData')) {
      // do something
       } ....
```

The problem is that it always seems to find HiddenData even though sometimes there is none.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
if ($(this).find('.HiddenData').length > 0) {
  // do something
} ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options depending upon what you want to do if you find the element you're looking for:

1) If the thing you want to do is a jQuery method and you want it to operate on the thing you're looking for, then you don't need an `if` statement.  You can just specify the jQuery methods.  If there are no matching elements found, it just won't do anything.

```
$(this).find(".HiddenData").fadeIn();
```

2) If the thing you want to do is a jQuery method and you want it to operate on the parent,  then you also don't need an `if` statement.  You can just specify the jQuery methods and use the `.has()` method instead of `.find()`.  If there are no matching elements found, it just won't do anything.

```
$(this).has(".HiddenData").css("color", "red");
```

3) If the logic is more complex and you need the `if` statement, then you can do the `if` statement like this:

```
if ($(this).find('.HiddenData').length > 0)
```